# Broken animation for applications overview

Tags: gnome, wayland, appmenu

When I press the application launcher, the icons flicker in their post-animation locations, and then the app menu animation starts.

The flicker is unwanted and I want to know how to get rid of it.

I've tried multiple screen recorders to give a visual demonstration, but much to my annoyance, they do not display the flicker (60fps playback)

Here's my system info:

```
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               kudos@UNKNOWN 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 21.04 x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: Swift SF314-42 V1.10 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 5.11.0-22-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 20 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2147 (dpkg), 4 (flatpak), 16 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: fish 3.2.2 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 3.38.4 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Juno 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Juno-palenight-v40 [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: BeautyLine [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: konsole 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500U with Radeon Graphics (6) @ 2.375GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: AMD ATI 03:00.0 Renoir 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 2135MiB / 7379MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

How would I stop the flicker from happening without disabling the animation altogether?

Comment: The question isn't a question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.  I changed the closing sentence to a question.